# Why is the last relation a function of $\eta$ and not a constant?

Tags: integration, functions, partial-differential-equations

In my notes there is the following:

$$U_{\xi \eta}(\xi, \eta)=0 \Rightarrow \frac{\partial}{\partial{\eta}} \left (\frac{\partial}{\partial{\xi}} U \right )=0 \\ \Rightarrow U_{\xi}(\xi, \eta)=a(\xi) \\ \Rightarrow \frac{\partial}{\partial{\xi}}\left (U(\xi, \eta)\right )=\frac{\partial}{\partial{\xi}}\left (\int_0^{\xi}a(s)ds\right ) \\ \Rightarrow \frac{\partial}{\partial{\xi}}\left (U(\xi, \eta)-\int_0^{\xi}a(s)ds\right )=0 \\ \Rightarrow U(\xi, \eta)-\int_0^{\xi}a(s)ds=B(\eta)$$

Why is the last relation a function of $\eta$ and not a constant??

Comment: can you see that  $u_{xy} = 0$ iff $u = f(x) + g(y).$ assume all the smoothness on $u, f, g?$

Comment: I see... Thanks!!! :-) @abel
$$$$ 
I am looking at the problem $$u_{tt}(x, t)-u_{xt}(x, t)=0 \\ u(x, 0)=f(x) \\ u_t(x, 0)=g(x)$$ 

Does it stand that $$u_{xt}=u_{tx}$$ ??

Comment: yes. for smooth functions $u_{tx} = u_{xt}.$  but here you have more: $0=\frac{\partial}{\partial t} (u_t - u_x) = u_{tt} - u_{xt}$  so $u_t - u_x = g(x) - f(x).$

Comment: So is $u$ a smooth function?? @abel

Comment: you have $u$ at least twice differentiable; or you will not be able to write $u_{tt} - u_{xt} = 0.$ it is true that $u_{xt} = u_{tx}.$

Comment: So that this equlaity holds it should stand that $$u \in C^{2,2}$$ right?? @abel

Comment: yes, i think so.

Comment: Do I have to write at the beginning "We assume that $u \in C^{2,2}$. ?? Or do I not have to ?? @abel

Comment: it is ok to write $u \in C^{2,2}$

Comment: Can we say: "Because $u \in C^{2,2}$ we have that $u_{xt}=u_{tx}$." ?? @abel

Comment: yes. it should be fine.

Comment: Ok... Thank you!!! :-) @abel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because just the derivative with respect to $\xi$ must be zero (according to the second last line) and this is true even if $B$ depends on $\eta$:
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial{\xi}}\left (U(\xi, \eta)-\int_0^{\xi}a(s)ds\right ) = \frac{\partial}{\partial \xi} B(\eta) = 0.$$

The same argument was already used in the second line.

Comment: I understand... Thank you!!! :-) 
$$$$ 

I am looking at the problem $$u_{tt}(x, t)-u_{xt}(x, t)=0 \\ u(x, 0)=f(x) \\ u_t(x, 0)=g(x)$$ 

Does it stand that $$u_{xt}=u_{tx}$$ ??

Comment: Yes, this usually holds. Formally it depends on your requirements on $u$: If you just ask for second derivatives of $u$ to exist, it is not a priori clear that you can exchange their order. If you require $u \in C^2$ (i.e. also continuity of the second derivatives), which one usually does, you can apply [Schwartz' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives#Schwarz.27_theorem) to exchange the order.

Comment: Do I have to write that we assume that $u \in C^{2,2}$ or is it known?? @Three.OneFour

Comment: If you want to be formal you have to assume $u \in C^2$, which is not an unreasonable requirement at all. If you can show uniqueness of the original pde and you can construct a $C^2$ solution of the $u_{tx}$-version you have shown that this is no assumption at all.

Comment: Ok... Thank you!!! :-) @Three.OneFour